# Swift Strings appear to mishandle carriage returns and newlines together

Tags: swift, bluetooth, swift4

For context, the app I'm developing is using a Bluetooth UART connection, and that's how I discovered this apparent issue.

When ending my messages with "/r/n" Swift ignores the newline when considering the length of the string. I can actually add a SECOND newline, but that introduces UART bugs.

Here's some code that outlines my issue:

```
var str = "Hey Apple"
print(str.count) //9
str += "\r" //"Hey Apple\r"
print(str.count) //10
str += "\n" //"Hey Apple\r\n"
print(str.count) //10
str += "\n" //"Hey Apple\r\n\n"
print(str.count) //11


var str2 = "Uh, hello?"
print(str2.count) //10
str2 += "\n" //"Uh, hello?\n"
print(str2.count) //11
str2 += "\n" //"Uh, hello?\n\n"
print(str2.count) //12
str2 += "\r" //"Uh, hello?\n\n\r"
print(str2.count) //13
```

There's something fishy here, and I don't know why.

Ideas?

Comment: you should print `str2.count` at the bottom

Comment: @WeiJay True! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `"\r"` and `"\r\n"` count as a single "extended Unicode grapheme
cluster", and that is what `str.count` counts (compare
["Strings and Characters"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) in the Swift
reference and [Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30) in the Swift blog).

If you convert the string to UTF-8 data for sending it via Bluetooth
and determine the actual length of the data

```
let data = Data(str.utf8)
let count = data.count // == str.utf8.count
```

then everything works as expected:

```
var str = "Hey Apple"
print(Data(str.utf8) as NSData) // <48657920 4170706c 65>
print(Data(str.utf8).count) // 9

str += "\r" //"Hey Apple\r"
print(Data(str.utf8) as NSData) // <48657920 4170706c 650d>
print(Data(str.utf8).count) // 10

str += "\n" //"Hey Apple\r\n"
print(Data(str.utf8) as NSData) // <48657920 4170706c 650d0a>
print(Data(str.utf8).count) // 11

str += "\n" //"Hey Apple\r\n\n"
print(Data(str.utf8) as NSData) // <48657920 4170706c 650d0a0a>
print(Data(str.utf8).count) // 12
```